# how to enable a disabled event handler with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, settimeout, eventhandler

```
$("#messageArea").keydown(function(e) {                             
    if((e.which != 13) && (e.keyCode != 27)) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.off();
        socket.emit("imTyping");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.on();
        }, 2000);
    } 
});
```

I'm trying to create a chat app that lets one person know when the other person is typing. This event handler listens for any key press (except enter and esc) and emits the "imTyping" message to the server. After THIS event handler is called, I want to disable (so I don't send a million messages to the server) and then enable it again after 2 seconds. That isn't happening, once it disables it, it PERMANENTLY disables it.

Also I have other event handlers for the messageArea element, so I only want to turn of THIS handler, and not any of the others.

Comment: Yes, `.off()` *removes* the event handler, as indicated pretty clearly in [its documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/). (And calling `.off()` with no arguments removes *all* of the event handlers from the element(s) in question.) Have you tried setting a flag `enabled = true` and then testing `if (enabled)`? Set the flag to `false` at the point where you currently remove the event handler, and back to true in your timeout callback. I find that approach cleaner than adding and removing the same handlers.

Comment: Why not using `focus` instead of `keydown` ?

Comment: @Zakaria that's not really an accurate way to find out when the user is typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract into a named function and pass in the correct parameters when unbinding/rebinding

```
$("#messageArea").keydown(typingKeydown);

function typingKeydown(e) {                             
    if((e.which != 13) && (e.keyCode != 27)) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.off('keydown', typingKeydown);
        socket.emit("imTyping");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.on('keydown', typingKeydown);
        }, 2000);
    } 
}
```

Comment: that's disabling the rest of the event handlers (i have more than one keydown event handler for #messageArea

Comment: @Rockstar5645, ah, in that case, pass in the handler to off. See my updated answer

Comment: @Rockstar5645, You should use `event.namespace` when unbind event.  like `$("#messageArea").on('keydown.myNamespace', typingKeydown);`